# PowerBI filter to change table data

Tags: powerbi, dax

This is kind of an ambitious question for the current release of PowerBI.

I don't think this is possible, but what I would like to do is create a filter so that the user can select the first day of the week on the report, and then have that selection effect the tables in the table viewer (as opposed to only affecting the report). Does anyone know if this is possible? And if so, how can this be accomplished?

I'm using PowerBI tables as source data for Excel, so what I want is so that the user can specify "Monday" "Tuesday" etc. as the first day of the week and then that will somehow update the tables.

Comment: Have you tried using an **Slicer**? **Field** can be the seven days of the week, and if you turn off **Single Select**, then you can select multiple days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is impossible, but there are a few posts suggesting this as an idea for future updates such as this one: https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/9414921-input-fields

Answer (score 1):

So you want to be able to use a filter to change the week day order in your table visualisations?

It is possible. Here's a proof of a concept:

Data:

```
MyTable(date, value)
01/01/2000, 5
02/01/2000, 8
...

StartOfTheWeek(index, name)
1, Monday
2, Tuesday
...

WeekDay(index, name)
1, Monday
2, Tuesday
...
```

Calculated column in MyTable:

```
WeekDay = WEEKDAY(MyTable[date])
```

Measure:

```
NewIndex = 
  mod(FIRSTNONBLANK('WeekDay'[index], 1) -
  FIRSTNONBLANK(StartOfTheWeek[index], 1), 7) + 1
```

Relationship between `MyTable.WeekDay` and `WeekDay.index`

Add:

- table visual with `NewIndex`, `WeekDay.name` and `MyTable.value`,
- slicer on `StartOfTheWeek.name`

Click on `NewIndex` on the table visual to sort.

Result:

[image]

---

If you don't want to see `newIndex` column in your table, shrink its width to minimal. Obviously if you ever need to export table data it will have that column.

---

Not sure how best to order week days in `StartOfTheWeek` slicer, quick and dirty workaround is to change names to `1.Monday`, `2.Tuesday`...